# Moving from numpy arrays to apply_ufunc

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

So far using numpy arrays to run computationally heavy code. I have two arrays, A and B that have both shapes `(n, NX, NY)`. I have a function that loops over `NX` and `NY` for A and B and does calculations along direction `n`. It returns 4 scalars, which I stick in the sample `(NX, NY)` location in their respective output arrays.

I want to now expand this to select the A and B arrays from an xarray with shape `(n, NX, NY, nt)`. I to loop over all the arrays along dimension 0 (`nt`), set the corresponding array to A, and then loop over the next arrays sequentially along `nt` to be B.

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Generate a sample dataset

time = pd.date_range(start="2017/07/02", end="2017/10/01", freq="10D")
reference_time = pd.Timestamp("2020-07-01")
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)
refl = np.random.rand(4, 100, 100, len(time))
ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        refl=(["band", "x", "y", "time"], refl),
    ),
    cords=dict(
        band=["B02", "B03", "B04", "B05"],
        x=x,
        y=y,
        time=time,
        reference_time=reference_time,
    ),
)

###This yields the following dataset
###<xarray.Dataset>
###Dimensions:         (band: 4, x: 100, y: 100, time: 10)
###Coordinates:
###  * band            (band) <U3 'B02' 'B03' 'B04' 'B05'
###  * x               (x) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
###  * y               (y) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
###  * time            (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-07-02 2017-07-12 ... 2017-09-30
###    reference_time  datetime64[ns] 2020-07-01
###Data variables:
###    refl            (band, x, y, time) float64 0.4509 0.1378 ... ###0.8169 0.3663

# We want to apply a function to different time slices 
# pixel-by-pixel. Let's select two time slices and the function 
# `func`:


t0 = ds.isel({"time":0})
t1 = ds.isel({"time":-1})

def func(t0, t1):
    """Returns a two-element tuple with Nx*Ny arrays"""
    # Check type so I can call with dataset or array
    if type(t0) == np.ndarray and type(t1) == np.ndarray:
        return (np.mean(t0-t1, axis=0),
                np.mean(t0+t1, axis=0))
    else:
        return (np.mean(t0.refl.values-t1.refl.values, axis=0),
                np.mean(t0.refl.values+t1.refl.values, axis=0))

s = xr.apply_ufunc(func, t0, t1,
                 input_core_dims = [["band", "x", "y"],["band", "x", "y"]],
                 output_dtypes=[[float, float], [float, float]],
                   )
```

This runs, and it returns a convoluted numpy object. However, this is just extracting the data and running the original numpy function. It is not taking any advantage of dask (although not shown the dataset is chunked), and ultimately, I want to exploit the ability of dask for parallel processing to process different space and time slices in parallel as follows:

```py
resultX = []
resultY = []
for it0 in range(len(ds.time)):
    for it1 in range(it0+1, ds.time):
        t0 = ds.isel({"time": it0})
        t1 = ds.isel({"time": it1})
        resultA, resultB = xr.apply_ufunc(func, t0, t1, ....)
        resultX.append(resultA)
        resultY.append(resultB)
```

Comment: any chance you could provide a [mre]? it can be hard to talk about dask in the abstract, since something that might work at one scale may be totally different at another. generally, this should work fine if your arrays are chunked in (NX, NY) and so your operation only works on the other dimensions. just develop a function that would work on a subset of the data and then apply that to each block. but it's hard to tell where bottlenecks/opportunities might be without seeing actual code

Comment: Updated question with a MWE. I think `map_blocks` may be what I am after here, though.